# Outlook Autodiscover Protocol Updated? (or broken?)

Tags: email, email-server, outlook, outlook-2010, autodiscovery

I have set up email autodiscovery on a non-Exchange email server per [this technet article][1], and when testing with Outlook 2015, it does not work.

Outlook hits the server multiple times, retrieving autodiscover.xml from example.com, autodiscover.example.com as well as the same but with passing the user's credentials via HTTP AUTH headers.  So it seems to be retrieving the xml file but does not like the contents thereof.

I also used the [Microsoft testing tool][2] and passed the "Outlook Autodiscover" test, but not the "Outlook Connectivity" test, which may also indicate that my xml is bad, but the latter may only work if you point to an Exchange server, which is not the case here.

I followed the [instructions][1] carefully, so I am wondering if Microsoft has updated Outlook's autoconfiguration protocol or broken it somehow with non-Exchange servers?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not aware of "outlook autodiscovery" working at all without the "proper" DNS TXT and SRV records in your domain.  But these are non-standard and may differ depending on how you, your ISP, or your hosting provider have configured your email SERVER and which server it is.

here are some samples of ISP, Microsfot , and tech help blogs showing the variety this solution can take to resolve ....

ISP SPecific
http://www.rackspace.com/apps/support/portal/1218
http://kb.intermedia.net/article/1306

http://www.virtuworks.com/how-to-setup-outlook-autodiscovery-for-your-domain/

Microsoft
https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/940881
http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2014/10/02/how-to-check-exchange-autodiscover-srv-record-using-nslookup.aspx

3rd party Blogs
https://acbrownit.wordpress.com/2012/12/20/internal-dns-and-exchange-autodiscover/

Comment: Appreciate your reply, but clearly DNS is not the problem if Outlook is hitting the server AND if I pass Microsoft's autodiscover test. It is implied that my DNS is fine.

Comment: Doesn't outlook 15 authenticate the SRV record to verify that the autodiscover.xml file is valid? - Again, read the article david posted. http://blogs.technet.com/b/rmilne/archive/2014/10/02/how-to-check-exchange-autodiscover-srv-record-using-nslookup.aspx

Comment: What do you mean "authenticate the SRV record"? As I've explained, outlook is able to contact the server - it is NOT an issue of DNS being wrong. I ALSO explained that the server passes the Microsoft Outlook autodiscover test. All my DNS is in order (yes, including SRV entries); links provided are irrelevant to the question - Outlook doesn't like the xml it is seeing.

Comment: an incredible example of why putting links as answers is bad.